Can I make the depth of field be independent of scale?


Is there any way to make the depth of field remain a constant, regardless of scale? Many workflows in 3D are independent of scale, why is this so different? Edit:I would like the distance between the camera and focal object to be the single variable.
The first image is scale of 1, and the second is scale of .1

The depth of field setting tries to replicate real-life aperture effects which are very dependent on actual distances between camera and objects. I don't know what you have in mind when you say "many workflows are independent of scale", most certainly not those which try to replicate real-life things like smoke, water, rigid body and other simulations, scene lighting and also camera settings. If you want the depth of field to change with the scale (in order to keep the same look), you might need a driver for the aperture value - but even then it might not look exactly the same.

To add to Gordon's comment, the blur is influenced by 2 factors : aperture and sensor size. For the latter, that's the reason you get huge blur on miniature photo and have almost none on landscapes (well lens size and aperture factor in too, what matters is the camera size). Only solution I see is to drive aperture and/or sensor on some property as pointed out by Gordon. I'm not sure how one could answer your question. I'd say the answer is no, you can't. Depth blur is depend on scale.

Thank you for your help. I have been attempting some crazy camera motion and this problem is paramount
